# CMake fails compilation

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cocos2d-x

I am trying to compile cocos2d-x 3.5 on openSUSE 13.2 and i get the following error in .log file:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec846787943/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fno-exceptions -std=c99    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec846787943
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -fno-exceptions -std=c99     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec846787943 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec846787943.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec846787943' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec846787943] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec846787943/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec846787943/fast] Error 2

File /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec3838281423/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fno-exceptions -std=c99 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3838281423
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -fno-exceptions -std=c99 -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3838281423 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3838281423.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3838281423' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3838281423] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/humman/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3838281423/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec3838281423/fast] Error 2
```

I installed the dependencies and libraries manually, but I still get this error. Does anyone know whats going on?

Note: when i try to compile, the first 2 lines are:

```
~/android-dev/cocos2d-x-3.5/cocos2d-x-3.5/build/linux-build> cmake ../..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (cmake_policy):
  Policy "CMP0054" is not known to this version of CMake.
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, I just did comment this lines out in the CMakeList.txt file

```
#if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3)
    #cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)
#endif()
```

but now, when I use make command (No matter where, using NetBeans or terminal) it ends with this error at 98% (after about 15mins compiling)

```
[ 98%] Built target cocos2d
[ 98%] Built target MyGame_CORE_PRE_BUILD
MyGame_PRE_BUILD ...
[ 98%] Built target MyGame_PRE_BUILD
Linking CXX executable bin/MyGame
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: lib/libcocos2d.a(CCSpriteFrameCache.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZSt28_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erasePSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseRS_@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/build.make:164: recipe for target 'bin/MyGame' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/MyGame] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea??

---

Solved, If anyone has the same problem, just use cmake with the argument -pthread and then you will be able to build using make. If you wanna build using NetBeans, u have to leave only the -G "Unix..." argument and add in the CMakefile.txt the line: set(-pthread) --I did add it at the top-- and thats all, it should be everything ok :D cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a long-standing CMake bug. Something else is going wrong, CMake gets confused, and reports this spurious problem instead of the real error.

Look for "thread" in your CMakeLists.txt file and temporarily remove that.